# How to change font inside \DeclareMathOperator?

Tags: fonts, amsmath, math-operators

LaTeX friends. I need to change the font inside `\DeclareMathOperator`, but my initial attempt failed, as the example below shows. How can I achieve the desired result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% change to Courier font family
\newcommand\myfont[1]{{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}
\DeclareMathOperator\FMod{\myfont{Mod}}

\begin{document}

$\Mod A$% regular DeclareMathFont

$\FMod A$% attempt to change the font. No joy!
 
$\text{\myfont{Mod}}\,A$% the desired result. This has to be achieved using \DeclareMathFont

\end{document}
```

Edit: I want this font change for only one operator and I need the same functionality provided by `\DeclareMathOperator` (possibility of limits, spacing between operator and operand, etc.)

Comment: It's nice to see you back, Gonzalo!  The font used for operators is defined in `amsopn` as `\operatorfont` (and an internal form).  Look at the description of that command in `amsopn.pdf` (included in the current version of the `amsmath` bundle on CTAN).

Comment: Ditto :). Do you want to change the font for all operators? If not, can you say a bit about why you need to achieve this result with `\DeclareMathOperator` specifically?

Comment: Thanks, @barbarabeeton and cfr. I want to change the font only for one operator. The operator has to have the same functionality that the ones declared with \DeclareMathOperator but using a different font.

Comment: @cfr after your questions I added some information to my post.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Rewelcome to a great user.

Comment: I'm very happy to see you again here!

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you!

Comment: @egreg Thank you, egreg! I am also happy to see you still around here. Thanks also for you answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` you're essentially defining a shorthand for `\operatorname{foo}`.

Well, actually of

```
\qopname\relax o{foo}
```

which, in turn is

```
\mathop {\relax\kern\z@\operator@font foo}\csname nolimits@\endcsname
```

and now we want to see what `\operator@font` does:

```
\mathgroup\symoperators
```

Thus the font choice is of a math font, not a text font. And `\fontfamily` will do nothing.

In your case, you probably want

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\FMod}{\mathtt{Mod}}
```

where you have allocated `pcr` as the font for `\mathtt`. The LaTeX kernel does

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
```

and you likely want

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{OT1}{pcr}{m}{n}
```

If you don't want to change the default `\mathtt`, you can use `\text`:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\FMod}{\text{\usefont{OT1}{pcr}{m}{n}Mod}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% change to Courier font family
\newcommand\myfont{\usefont{OT1}{pcr}{m}{n}}
\DeclareMathOperator\Mod{Mod}
\DeclareMathOperator\FMod{\text{\myfont Mod}}

\begin{document}

$\Mod A$% regular DeclareMathFont

$\FMod A$% attempt to change the font: good!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that just `\fontfamily{pcr}` isn't enough: in the context of a theorem statement (using italics), the operator name would be slanted.